# How does test and je/jne work

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, lldb

Okay so I started working a little with assembly. I began with the following instructions:

```
test       al, al
jne        0x1000bffcc
```

Using the debugger, I wanted the code to not jump to address `0x1000bffcc` so I set a breakpoint on the `jne` instruction and then inverted the al register using following lldb command:

```
expr $al = 1
```

This worked well so I continued until I stumbled across the following, very similar instruction pair:

```
test       al, al
je         0x1000bffcc
```

While this looks similar, inverting the `al` register doesn't seem to have an affect. It keeps on jumping to address `0x1000bffcc`. So I did some research and figured out that test runs a logical `AND` with `al` itself and then sets the zero flag or `ZF` accordingly. This leads to two questions:

- Why did it help to invert the `al` register in the first example?
- Why does it not work in the second example?
- How can I use the debugger to make the code not jump in the second example?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: When you say that you "inverted" `al`, what does that mean exactly in the second case? That you set it to zero?

Comment: Assuming you set `al` to zero in the second case, maybe you set it too late? Sometime is easy stopping one instruction late with debuggers :)

Comment: You are setting the breakpoint on the wrong instruction.  Set it on TEST, not the branch instruction.  Or  change the Z flag.

Comment: Once you ran the "test" instruction, the flag ZF is already set so you're not jumping on the first case whatever value you put in AL at your first breakpoint I guess. Similarly, you're jumping anyway in the second case since the test instruction has already been executed and the ZF flag set. Put your breakpoint on the test instruction, or modify directly AL.

Comment: @Michael Okay by inverting I basically meant trying both cases.

Comment: @knm241 well I also tried it before the test instruction which didn't help either.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried setting it on test but that didn't work. Not even for example 1.

Comment: @YannHamdaoui if I don't modify al for the first example, I actually do jump. That would make sense, breaking on test and setting al doesn't help though.

Comment: @larcus94, Mmmh. What is your architecture ? What value do you set $al to in the second case, 1 too ? If yes, can you try with 0 instead ? I don't know lldb that much, but what's strange anyway is that even if for some reason the test is recomputed (breakpoint stop at the beggining of the instruction e.g.), setting AL to 1 should set ZF to 0 after the test and thus trigger the JNE-jump rather than avoiding it...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
test    al, al
jne     0x1000bffcc
```

The `test` instruction performs a logical *and* of the two operands and sets [the CPU flags register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) according to the result (which is not stored anywhere).  If `al` is zero, the anded result is zero and that sets the Z flag.  If `al` is nonzero, it clears the Z flag.  (Other flags, such as **C**arry, o**V**erflow, **S**ign, **P**arity, etc. are affected too, but this code has no instruction testing them.)

The `jne` instruction alters EIP if the Z flag is not set.  There is another mnemonic for the same operation called `jnz`.

If you let the `test` instruction execute and then changed `al` before the conditional jump instruction, the conditional jump is still going to do whatever it was going to do before altering `al`.  That is because the value of `al` no longer affects the conditional jump.  If you change the value before the test, then it will work as expected.

As for *why* changing it sometimes has an effect:  It must be because the revised value of `al` is affecting other logic.

To use the debugger to make the instruction not jump, change the flags such that the Z flag is set.  It might be called ZF, or you might have to modify the bit in the EFLAGS register.  How to do this varies by the debugger and possibly its revision.

Comment: "As for why changing it sometimes has an effect: It must be because the revised value of al is affecting other logic." What does that mean exactly? I though je/jne would only take the ZF into account? And setting the al register to one before testing it doesn't make the process jump the way I want it to. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Turns out that AL didn't have an effect on it.

Comment: It was probably that the `jne` was already going to jump in the direction you wanted.  Unless changing `al` in the debugger affected the flags of the target, too, which would be a bug in the debugger, IMO.  `jcc` only depends on flags, so changing `al` after `test` ran would have no effect, as wallyk says.